# ABS to AppCompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat, oncreateoptionsmenu

I am trying now to change `ABS` actionbar to `AppCompat`. I need to force the following code, whitch works fine with `SherlockFragment`, to work in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. I need to add custom view into `Menu`. How can I do this right in `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    View view = getLayoutInflater(getArguments()).inflate(R.layout.some_custom_layout, null);
    menu.add("ITEM").setActionView(view).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
```

and use

```
void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

then change

```
menu.add("ITEM").setActionView(view).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

to

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.add("SWITCHER");
MenuItemCompat.setActionView(menuItem, view);
MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```